# dojo enhancedGrid selection

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I have an enhancedGrid with 9000+ elements, initialized as follows:

```
var grid_invoices = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    id: 'grid_invoices',
    keepSelection: true,
    rowSelector: false,
    selectable: true,
    escapeHTMLInData: false,
    rowsPerPage: 250,
    keepRows: 1000,
    delayScroll: true,
    noDataMessage: "Aucun résultat",
    queryOptions: {ignoreCase: true},
    plugins: {
        indirectSelection: {headerSelector:true, styles:"text-align: center;padding:5px;"},
        search: false
    }
},
document.createElement('div'));
```

I need to do a csv export of selected elements of the grid. If I select <= 1000 elements no problem, here the actual code

```
var downloadPdfIframeName = "downloadPdfIframe",
  iframe = dojo.io.iframe.create(downloadPdfIframeName),
  count = grid_invoices.selection.getSelectedCount();
if (count > 0 && count < 1000) {
  var lst = getGridSelection('grid_invoices', 'id'),
    ids = lst.join(',');
  dojo.io.iframe.setSrc(iframe, "/invoices/exportcsv/ids/" + ids, true);
} else if (count == 0) {
  dojo.io.iframe.setSrc(iframe, "/invoices/exportcsv?" + dojo.objectToQuery(getSearchFilterInvoice()), true);
}
```

now, I'd like to be able to export any elements I want (>1000 possibly) but I don't know where to start.

The grid is a lazy loaded grid so there's no possibility of retrieving all ids with one simple query, and even if that would be possible, I cannot just chain the ids to the GET HTTP QUERY (query limit)

I thought of doing something like "*see if everything is selected and build a custom php filter*" but if the user select, let's say, 5000 records, I don't have a clue of what to do.

Can someone point me to the good direction ?

Comment: The selectRange(type, start, end): attribute of [dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid.plugins.Selector](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Selector.html#dojox-grid-enhancedgrid-plugins-selector) may help you.

Comment: Have you tried directly accessing the store that is attached to the grid to get the data?

Comment: Hum no, let me try that